# Java EE/OmniFaces: Project Setup - LinkageError using WildFly

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, omnifaces

Trying to integrate OmniFaces into a Java EE Web Project.

When implementing the following simple listener method, I receive linkage errors. I am using the WebSphere application server.

What's going on here?

```
public void useCreditCardChanged(javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent event) {
    Boolean oldVal = (Boolean) event.getOldValue();
    Boolean newVal = (Boolean) event.getNewValue();
    if (oldVal!=null) {
        this.useCreditCard = newVal;
    }
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
}
```

and the log-files:

```
11:25:48.806 S [ConfigureListene  257] Critical error during deployment: : 
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.omnifaces.taghandler.ValidateUniqueColumn.processValueChange(Ljavax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent;)V" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/omnifaces/taghandler/ValidateUniqueColumn, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for interface javax/faces/event/ValueChangeListener have different Class objects for the type (Ljavax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent;)V used in the signature
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:325) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:376) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:427) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:378) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:321) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:270) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:437) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:86)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:71)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]

11:25:48.808 E [ServiceControlle 1955] MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./my-app: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./my-app: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.omnifaces.taghandler.ValidateUniqueColumn.processValueChange(Ljavax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent;)V" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/omnifaces/taghandler/ValidateUniqueColumn, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for interface javax/faces/event/ValueChangeListener have different Class objects for the type (Ljavax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent;)V used in the signature
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:86)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:71)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    ... 3 more

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.omnifaces.taghandler.ValidateUniqueColumn.processValueChange(Ljavax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent;)V" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/omnifaces/taghandler/ValidateUniqueColumn, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for interface javax/faces/event/ValueChangeListener have different Class objects for the type (Ljavax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent;)V used in the signature
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:273)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
    ... 7 more

Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.omnifaces.taghandler.ValidateUniqueColumn.processValueChange(Ljavax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent;)V" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/omnifaces/taghandler/ValidateUniqueColumn, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for interface javax/faces/event/ValueChangeListener have different Class objects for the type (Ljavax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent;)V used in the signature
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:325)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:376)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:427)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:378)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:321)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:270)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:437)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.omnifaces.taghandler.ValidateUniqueColumn.processValueChange(Ljavax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent;)V" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/omnifaces/taghandler/ValidateUniqueColumn, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for interface javax/faces/event/ValueChangeListener **have different Class objects for the type (Ljavax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent;)V used in the signature**

You've multiple different versioned JSF API classes in webapp's runtime classpath. In this particular problem, specifically for the `javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent` class multiple different versions have been found in the webapp's runtime classpath. In other words, the webapp's runtime classpath is dirty. Most likely you've JARs in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` which do not belong there, because the appserver itself already ships those libraries out the box, such as Java EE and JSF.

Then there's another strange thing in your question. You're talking about [IBM WebSphere](http://www.ibm.com/software/websphere) and you've tagged `[websphere]`, but the appserver specific classes listed in the stack trace clearly tells that it's [JBoss WildFly](http://wildfly.org), which is a completely different server, but perhaps explains why you added `[jboss]` tag as well. Again, those are two completely different servers. Know what you're using.

In any case, explore the webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` and get rid of libraries which are already provided by the appserver itself, such as `javaee.jar`, `jsf-api.jar`, etc.

Comment: First, thanks a lot for your answer and the WildFly hint.We switched from Glassfish to WildFly and talked about a lot of app servers. Sorry for the confusion. Well you are right, as explained in my other post (http://goo.gl/GZttN2) I have included  my JSF implementation (jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar) on both server site and as EJB library. If I don't add it to my EJB lib, I can compile but my beans are null caused by: "class loading error: Type javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent from [Module "deployment.myApp.ear.APPcore.jar:main" from Service Module Loader] not found."

Comment: Your business tier (EJB) should be free of any JSF (and Servlet) artifacts. JSF (and OmniFaces) doesn't belong in business tier, but only in web tier (WAR). Otherwise your business tier isn't reusable on other web tiers such as JAX-RS, Spring MVC, etc. You need to move the JSF specific code from EJB to WAR and make absolutely sure that no one of your service classes has a (indirect) dependency on `javax.faces.*` classes.

Comment: Wow, that means that our project setup is completely wrong from this point of view. It's not so easy to identify the web and business tier since CDI beans can be bound easily to the web tier and provide business logics. Strong decisions at this point, isn't it?

Comment: CDI is indeed usable on both tiers. Okay, looks like it's time for some refactoring. To start, `javax.faces.*`, `javax.servlet.*`, `javax.el.*` does **not** belong in the business tier. The business tier should only offer JPA `@Entity` classes, EJB `@Stateless`, `@Stateful`, etc classes and if necessary some non-transactional business services (those which doesn't interact with DB at all, such as a web scraper, those can indeed just be `@Named`). Those services are in turn to be `@Inject`ed in JSF managed beans in web tier which in turn are referenced by Facelets (XHTML) files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this short explanations. It's indeed time for some refactoring now. i.e. CDI beans should basically be used as JSF managed beans on web tier and delegate the business logic to ejb's/cdi's on business tier to make a strong cut between them, right?

Comment: That's correct. See also "Designing business/service layer" and other topics listed here: https://jsf.zeef.com/bauke.scholtz#block_377

Comment: Nice hints Bauke, thanks! By the way: zeef.com looks nice. Check your mailbox. Maybe you are interested advising us on some more jee details.

Comment: I cleaned the code by doing the above-mentioned refactoring yesterday and at first sight it looks all well. My faces-implementation is provided by WildFly runtime. My primefaces/omnifaces libraries are part of my Web-Archive. Now, my simple test bean is not instantiated because of a class loading error: Type javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent from [Module "deployment.myApp.ear.appCore.jar:main" from Service Module Loader] not found. That classloading behavior seems to be a science on its own. :/